# execute of two consecutive commands in the linux background

Tags: linux

I am newbie in Linux and would like to run the two commands in background as follows:

```
nohup ./command1 && ./command2 &
```

However, the command 2 is not executed. What is the problem?

I also tried as follows:

```
nohup ./command1 ; ./command2 &
```

but the problem so exists.

Comment: bash tries first to execute `nohup ./command1`, then `./command2 &`. Only when the first command is finished, it will start the second in the background. Do you want to run both commands in parallel in the background or sequentially in the background?

Comment: I want to run sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

```
nohup ./command1 &
nohup ./command2 &
```

You could put them on the same line because the `&` is a command separator just like `;`.

Note that you need one `nohup` in front of each command which should run under `nohup`.

(Alternatively, `nohup sh -c 'command1; command2' &` if you want to run them sequentially in the background.)

Comment: I tried both suggestions but in the first one, i.e. ```nohup ./command1 &
nohup ./command2 &``` the comand2 didn't execute. However, the second one, i.e, ```nohup sh -c 'command1; command2' &``` worked properly.

Comment: You are probably looking in the wrong place. `nohup` will overwrite `nohup.out` so if that's where you are looking, it got overwritten when you ran the second command. Probably change `command1` and `command2` so that they independently write to a unique temporary file which you can examine afterwards, or something. Demo: https://ideone.com/vPmC6L